# How to set a custom Build Version in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, devops, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I am trying to set an environmental variable in a format of `YYYY.MM.DD.BuildId` for versioning binaries, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.  I need it available from the buildspec.yml file to reference in the compiler commands.  It doesn't seem like it should be this difficult, but I cannot seem to update the environmental variables with any kind of dynamic logic.

I've tried variations on this theme in the yaml file:

```
env:
  variables:
     BUILD_VERSION: "$(date +%Y.%m.%d).$(CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER)"
```

...but it always treats the build version as a literal value.  No substitution takes place.

I can't be the only person that's tried to do this sort of thing.  How can I make this work?  This is stupidly easy in Azure Devops, and trivial in Jenkins as well, so it's surprising how long I've been at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that in the build step, I could use the command shell to set the value I wanted for my compiler.  For example:

```
  build:
    commands:
      - export BUILD_VERSION=$(date +%Y.%m.%d).$CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER
      - echo Building version [$BUILD_VERSION]...
      - dotnet publish My.Project/My.Project.csproj --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp3.1 --output ./application --self-contained --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64 /p:AssemblyVersion=$BUILD_VERSION /p:AssemblyFileVersion=$BUILD_VERSION /p:FileVersion=$BUILD_VERSION
```

This allowed my binaries to be built with the proper file and build versions.